# Standard deviation of a quantum walk?

Tags: probability, markov-chains, random-walk, quantum-mechanics, quantum-computation

The standard deviation of a classical random walk with $n$ steps is $\sqrt n$ - [Standard deviation of a random walk](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/433069/random-walk-confusion). I have read in many places that the standard deviation of a quantum walk $n$ with a Hadamard transformation for the coin flip operation, and this makes sense intuitively because quantum constructive interference means the quantum walk diffuses more rapidly.

However I have not seen any derivation of how this conclusion was arrived. What is the derivation for the standard deviation of a quantum walk?

Comment: Been looking at various papers over the last few days and I STILL haven't found an answer to this, even thought lots of them mention this fact...you'd imagine there would actually be proof out there somewhere!